# get_headers returning error on new server

Tags: php, apache, cpanel, whm

I have created an image manipulation function on one of my old sites and this is run on a page that received the full url of the image as a get variable. Part of this function uses get_headers to get the content type of the requested file.

While this works on my old server I've recently moved to a new server and I remember having all kinds of trouble with this page but I think this was more server side with GD library.

I'm running the site on a dedicated server running php 5.4.X and WHm cPanel so I have full access to change and install things as I need.

**The Troublesome code**

```
<?php

//Get the file and set the headers to the file type
$file           = $_GET['file'];
$headers        = get_headers($file, 1);
header('Content-Type: '.$headers['Content-Type']);
```

**Page response**

```
Warning: get_headers(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in [Removed url] on line 5

Warning: get_headers([Removed url]): failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in [Removed url] on line 5

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at [Removed url]:5) in [Removed url] on line 6
```

The only thing I've changed server side is setting allow_url_fopen to on in WHM, everything else I've tried I've reset back after it not working.

Comment: How recently have you moved servers? It could be a DNS issue if the domain hasn't propagated yet.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a DNS resolution issue, if the address is proper and you recently changed your name
servers of the domain, or the A record for instance, then DNS "propagation" could be taking place. You might be able to get it quicker using google's public nameservers like so:

```
nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

Then set your nameservers:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8 
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Comment: Was pretty much writing out the exact same answer but you beat me to it :( You didn't beat me to the comment though!

Comment: You can also fix the problem temporarily (please remove this after the DNS change has kicked in) by adding the host to `/etc/hosts`.